# bxslider set min/max visible slides with custom pager

Tags: jquery, slider, thumbnails, bxslider

Hi guys I appreciate any assistance,

Basically I have a slider with 25 slides but I dont want all 25 thumbnails to show up, only 5 at a time
Here are some settings ive tried. I tried a lot of combinations with the max-min slides but nothing happened same with displaySlideQty,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#slider2').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  pause: 3000,
  minSlides: 1,
          maxSlides: 5,
          displaySlideQty : 5,
  slideMargin: 20,
  infiniteLoop: false,

});
<div class="slider">
<h3>Slideshow 2</h3>
<ul id="slider2">
  <li><img src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/5.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/6.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/5.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/6.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/5.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/6.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/5.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/6.jpg" /></li>      
</ul></div>
<div id="bx-pager">
  <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="4" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="5" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="6" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a> 
  <a data-slide-index="7" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="8" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="9" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a> 
  <a data-slide-index="10" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="11" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="12" href=""><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a>    
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/edgardo400/tEYjg/1/

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did:

I created two sliders so one will be the slider and the other a carousel that will help us as pager.

You can take a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/sanchitos/FpPAg/22/

Basic code:

```
var carousel;
var slider;
$(document).ready(function () {
    carousel = $('.slider4').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 300,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        pager: false

    });

    slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        captions: true,
        controls: false,
        pager: false
    });
});

function clicked(position) {
    slider.goToSlide(position);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider" style="width: auto; position: relative;">
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar0" title="Funky roots1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1" title="Funky roots2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar2" title="Funky roots3" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar3" title="Funky roots4" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar4" title="Funky roots5" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar5" title="Funky roots6" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6" title="Funky roots7" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7" title="Funky roots8" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8" title="Funky roots8" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9" title="Funky roots9" />
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="slider4">
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(0);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar0">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(1);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1">
             </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(2);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar2">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(3);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar3">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(4);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar4">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(5);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar5">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(6);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(7);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(8);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8">
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clicked(9);">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9">
            </a>

    </div>
</div>
```